# WaveOutWrite doesnt produce any sound... syeteo sinewave?

Tags: c++, winapi

what is wrong with that following code ?
Compiles and executes fine, but doesnt produce any sound... BTW could anyone point me to how produce stereo left and right sound ?

```
 void audio()
 {         WAVEHDR       _audioHeader;
           HWAVEOUT      _audioOut     = 0;
           WAVEFORMATEX  _audioStyle;

           _audioStyle.wFormatTag      = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
           _audioStyle.nChannels       = 1;
           _audioStyle.nSamplesPerSec  = 44100;
           _audioStyle.nAvgBytesPerSec = 44100 * 2;
           _audioStyle.nBlockAlign     = 2;
           _audioStyle.wBitsPerSample  = 16;
           _audioStyle.cbSize          = 0;

           _audioHeader.lpData          = new char[44100 * 2];
           _audioHeader.dwBufferLength  = 44100 * 2;
           _audioHeader.dwBytesRecorded = 0;
           _audioHeader.dwUser          = 0;
           _audioHeader.dwFlags         = WHDR_BEGINLOOP | WHDR_ENDLOOP;
           _audioHeader.dwLoops         = 0xFFFF;
           _audioHeader.lpNext          = NULL;
           _audioHeader.reserved        = 0;

           for(unsigned _x = 0; _x < _audioHeader.dwBufferLength / 2; _x += 2)
              { const
                double _byte = 128 + 127 * ::cos(double(_x) * 2.0 * M_PI * double(2400) / double(_audioStyle.nSamplesPerSec));

                _audioHeader.lpData[_x + 0] = (char)(_byte);
                _audioHeader.lpData[_x + 1] = (char)(_byte);
              }

           ::waveOutOpen(&_audioOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &_audioStyle, NULL, NULL, CALLBACK_NULL);
           ::waveOutPrepareHeader(&_audioOut, &_audioHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
           ::waveOutWrite(&_audioOut, &_audioHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

           ::Beep(1200, 500); ::Sleep(1000); ::Beep(2400, 500);

           if(_audioOut != 0)
             { ::waveOutReset(&_audioOut);
               ::waveOutClose(&_audioOut);

               ::delete [] _audioHeader.lpData;
             }
 }
```

Comment: A useful first step is to check for errors

Comment: well….error ? this sounds like a new word to me….lol... I do not see any….

Comment: That is, checking whether functions return an error code.

Comment: You do not see any errors because you aren't looking. Start by reading the documentation for [waveOutOpen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mmeapi/nf-mmeapi-waveoutopen), in full. Make sure you do not skip the section titled *"Return value"*. Do this for every other API call, and act on the information acquired.

Comment: you are right, sir

Answer (score 1):

after some research, I found that nBlockAlign has to be computed, wBitsPerSample reduced to 8, and mainly, as waveoutopen requires a pointer to HWAVEOUT, other functions only require the handle….

code became :

```
 {         WAVEHDR       _audioHeader;
           HWAVEOUT      _audioOut     = 0;
           WAVEFORMATEX  _audioStyle;

           _audioStyle.wFormatTag      = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
           _audioStyle.nChannels       = 2;
           _audioStyle.nSamplesPerSec  = 44100;
           _audioStyle.nAvgBytesPerSec = _audioStyle.nSamplesPerSec * _audioStyle.nChannels;
           _audioStyle.wBitsPerSample  = 8;
           _audioStyle.nBlockAlign     = (_audioStyle.wBitsPerSample / 8) * _audioStyle.nChannels;
           _audioStyle.cbSize          = 0;

           _audioHeader.dwBufferLength  = _audioStyle.nAvgBytesPerSec;
           _audioHeader.lpData          = new char[_audioHeader.dwBufferLength];
           _audioHeader.dwBytesRecorded = 0;
           _audioHeader.dwUser          = 0;
           _audioHeader.dwFlags         = WHDR_BEGINLOOP | WHDR_ENDLOOP;
           _audioHeader.dwLoops         = 0xFFFF;
           _audioHeader.lpNext          = NULL;
           _audioHeader.reserved        = 0;

           for(unsigned _x = 0; _x < _audioHeader.dwBufferLength; _x += 2)
              { const
                double _byte = ::cos(double(_x) * 2.0 * M_PI * double(2400) / double(_audioStyle.nSamplesPerSec));

                if(_x > (_audioHeader.dwBufferLength / 2))
                  { _audioHeader.lpData[_x + 0] = (char)(128 + 127 * 0);
                    _audioHeader.lpData[_x + 1] = (char)(128 + 127 * _byte);
                  }
                else
                  { _audioHeader.lpData[_x + 0] = (char)(128 + 127 * _byte);
                    _audioHeader.lpData[_x + 1] = (char)(128 + 127 * 0);
                  }
              }

           if(::waveOutOpen(&_audioOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &_audioStyle, NULL, NULL, CALLBACK_NULL) == 0)
             if(::waveOutPrepareHeader(_audioOut, &_audioHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR)) == 0)
               ::waveOutWrite(_audioOut, &_audioHeader, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

           ::Sleep(1000);

           if(_audioOut != 0)
             { ::waveOutReset(_audioOut);
               ::waveOutClose(_audioOut);

               ::delete [] _audioHeader.lpData;
             }
 }
```